# AppleScript to repeat action in the next window

Tags: applescript

I would like that if I press a certain keyboard shortcut (cmd + down arrow), the same will run on the next window in the same app.

Is an AppleScript the only want to get this functionality? I have never made an AppleScript before.

Comment: It may also depend on what the app is - I'd guess that most apps will not respond to a keypress on any but the frontmost window.

Comment: Obligatory AppleScript is a programming language and doesn't provide any listeners for executing a script, so you'll have to use something else to run your AppleScript when you type that shortcut.

Comment: You can simulate key presses in applescript... so what you could do is: **1.** Make Automator.app `Service` that launches [this `Applescript`](https://pastebin.com/CGmq8zw3) **2.** Make sure that `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts  > Keyboard > Move focus to next window` shortcut matches the one on the script ( line 10 ) **3.** Save the Service (`cmd+s`) and go give it a shortcut at `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts  > Services > Your_Automator_Service_Name`. Or something like that..... I wouldn't expect it to be very fast though.

Comment: @Joonas Thank you, that seems to be what I am looking for. But it doesn't run in my application, also not with the shortcut. I do get it to run from Automator with activating my app first https://pastebin.com/HraJsBpM

Comment: So it doesn't do anything? Did you try it with another application? I tested it in Chrome. It's possible those shortcuts don't work in that app because they conflict with other shortcuts or something. What if you try to trigger the window focus and end shortcuts manually in thst app? And then if those seem to work, try to trigger the script from the Apple menu > Services > Your script. Cause that shortcut may be conflicting too.

Comment: All the shortcuts I put in the script are already existing, meaning if I am in the app and press them, they work. The script is also not available from the services menu. When I add `tell application launch` in the beginning, and run from automator, it opens the app and applies the expected. Actually the Keyboard Maestro solution below works perfectly, just would be nice to solve this with applescript!

Comment: Make sure that the options in your Service are identical to [the highlighted part in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GkYi.png). This part defines when the script should be available. `No input` is basically `anything goes`.

Comment: As a side note. Try getting rid of those delays. If everything works as intended, they're not needed. Also I'm not sure if it would make it any faster, but you could try changing the key code for `cmd+arrow up` and `cmd+arrow down` to key codes for `Home` and `End`. At the very least that change would reduce the risk of shortcut conflicts. You say running it from automator works, but... this change should make it more reliable. Some applications don't like the osx native shortcuts for `home, end, page down, page up`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following Keyboard Maestro macro.

[image]